# В чем разница между сохранением Bitmap в byte[] с помощью ImageConverter и MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, массивы, .net, изображения, bitmap

Допустим, есть функция для перевода Bitmap в byte[]:

```
public byte[] BitmapToByte(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Не очень эффективно, зато просто и надежно. А главное - понятно, что получается в результате - файл в формате BMP (кстати, можно еще задать формат MemoryBmp, но в чем его смысл, я так и не смог уразуметь - буду благодарен, если кто-то просветит, хотя вопрос и не об этом).

Все хорошо, но я в порядке эксперимента попытался переделать функцию вот так:

```
public byte[] BitmapToByte(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    return (byte[])(new ImageConverter()).ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

В результате получается какая-то белиберда, явно не в формате BMP (хотя бы потому что первые два байта - не ASCII-коды символов "BM"). Но что именно получается - я так и не смог понять, хотя и гуглил, и stackoverflow читал.

В большинстве источников эти два способа подаются как альтернативные. Нашел только один вопрос на stackoverflow, там все же уточнялось, что формат другой. Но какой именно и как, какой опцией проконтролировать его выбор - непонятно.

Comment: Хм, интересно. А что за данные получаются в случае `ImageConverter`'а? Попробуйте взять, скажем, полностью зелёную картинку, и посмотреть, что за данные приходят и сколько.

Answer (score 5):

`ImageConverter` использует формат по умолчанию, то есть вызывает просто:

```
bitmap.Save(stream);
```

В зависимости от того, как вы создавали или загружали файл, формат может быть различным, например, GIF или PNG. Если не получается сохранить в оригинальном формате (например, ICO) или это приведёт к потерям (например, JPEG), то используется PNG. Если вы просто создали картинку, ни откуда не загружая, то тоже будет использован PNG.

Comment: Да, я создаю картинку (делаю скриншот). А можно как-нибудь указать, что мне нужен именно BMP?

Comment: @VadimTukaev Если вы хотите явно задавать формат, лучше использовать способ с потоком. `ImageConverter` делает *абсолютно* то же самое, только полагается на свойство `RawFormat` при сохранении.